# Photon number resolving is possible?

Tags: photons, quantum-optics

People from quantum optical often tend to say it's not possible to revolve photon numbers of a given light. Nevertheless, the photon number statistics have been measured very long time ago. How was it possible even a long time ago although we are still saying the photon number resolving capability is hardly possible.

Comment: What do you mean by a "very long time ago", and where have you seen people claiming it's not possible to resolve photon numbers? The answers to those questions will help provide context and make the answers more relevant. Note, in particular, that [a Google Scholar search for 'photon number resolving detector'](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=photon+number+resolving+detector) yields plenty of relevant results - but the sources you refer to might actually mean something narrower.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty If you look at the paper G. Breitenbach, S. Schiller, and J. Mlynek, "Measurement of the quantum states of squeezed light", Nature, 387, 471 (1997), there they measured the photon number statistics of the squeezed state of light. Even before such paper, people had distinguished sub- or super-Poissonian photon number distribution from the Poissonian photon number distribution.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Also, you can take a look at the following papers, where people have discussed how to resolve the photon number statistics with only on-off detectors. 
[1] M. J. Fitch, B. C. Jacobs, T. B. Pittman, and J. D. Franson, "Photon-number resolution using time-multiplexed single-photon detectors", Phys. Rev. A 68, 043814 (2003).
[2] Daryl Achilles , Christine Silberhorn , Cezary Sliwa , Konrad Banaszek , Ian A. Walmsley , Michael J. Fitch, Bryan C. Jacobs, Todd B. Pittman, and James D. Franson, "Photon-number-resolving detection using time-multiplexing", J. Mod. Opt. 51, 1499 (2004).

Comment: You should edit all of that literature into the question. In any case, that only answers the first question, and you should still show examples of people claiming that photon-number resolution is not possible. Context matters in these things, and if you don't provide any it's impossible to know what those texts are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

If the intensity of the light source is low, there is no problem in detecting single photons. [PM tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photomultiplier) are the devices known since ~1940 that allow to do that. However if the intensity of the light is high, the effective bandwidth of the electrical signal corresponding to the light intensity should be large to resolve the single photon events. For example to resolve two single-photon pulses separated by $10^{-9}$ s (such separation is very likely to occur at pretty low light levels ~ nW) you need to have electronics with couple GHz bandwidth at least, and even with current state of technology dealing with such frequency is quite challenging.

Comment: Having two single-photon pulses separated by 1ns is challenging on a quick-response level, but it's another thing entirely to have a single light pulse with two photons in it (in the Fock state $|2\rangle$), which no amount of bandwidth will help you solve. By 'photon-number resolving' people tend to mean the latter.